# CircleCI failing to run Maven tests due to chromedriver exe being parsed as Java file

Tags: maven, google-chrome, selenium, testng, circleci

Locally I can run `mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml -Dbrowser=chrome -Denv=staging` my tests run fine. I am using Maven, Testng, Selenium, and Chromedriver. When I run this in CircleCi, however, I get the following issue:

`Running TestSuite
/home/ubuntu/myproj/myproj-web-automation/DriversExe/chromedriver: 1: /home/ubuntu/myproj/myproj-web-automation/DriversExe/chromedriver: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

That folder path indeed holds the chromedriver.exe and I set the path with

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ProjectLocation+"/DriversExe/chromedriver");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This path is correct, since it does run on my local machine, and fails on my local machine if I change that path.

Why am I getting this error on CircleCI?

Comment: A little more information would be useful. Since the error message displays a ubuntu home directory, are you using the right version of chromedriver? chromedriver.exe is for windows. Secondly, check the permissions and if the execute as a program are enabled for this file.

Answer (score 0):

The error does gives us some hint on whats going wrong :

```
Running TestSuite /home/ubuntu/myproj/myproj-web-automation/DriversExe/chromedriver: 1: /home/ubuntu/myproj/myproj-web-automation/DriversExe/chromedriver: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Seems *Circle CI* is unable to resolve the value from `System.setProperty()`

### Solution :

- Upgrade your *JDK* version to the required level as mentioned in *Circle CI* guide/specs.
- Alternatively, you can provide the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* for a quick debug.
- As per your *Project Stucture* the following should work :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./DriversExe/chromedriver");
  ```